# Invoke HP Print Service plugin from app?

Tags: android, printers

With Samsung devices, I can see HP print service plugin is installed and few apps like Gallery can make use of it. Is there anyway an app can invoke and pass data to print?

Answer (score 0):

The Android Support Library PrintHelper class provides a simple way to print of images.

```
private void doPhotoPrint() {
    PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(getActivity());
    photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.droids);
    photoPrinter.printBitmap("droids.jpg - test print", bitmap);
}
```